# android api 28 - application not installing due to Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-networking

I installed my app on different versions and it works find , I recently tried to install it on android api 28 (android 9 ) and it doesn't get the data from internet and it shows me this error : 
"Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted"

after some searched , i've tried some approaches, i've tried some of them and finally reach to this

I created a file in xml directory :network_security_config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">marketaghili.ir</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and add this line to my application in manifest :

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

after that I made my apk file but its not installing , it just says the app not installed .

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Uninstall manually then reinstall ? You can also check if it doesn't come from Google Play Protect (something like "verify app installed via usb" in developper settings too)

Comment: @Kilarn123 i've tied , it doesn't work

Comment: You need to add  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `application` tag in manifest file. Also must be sure url starts with `https` not `http`

Comment: @Piyush we don't have ssl for our site , I don't think android make us to use https , I tried this code,  still not installing

Comment: The code should be ok if `marketaghili.ir` is valid. The installation problem might come from something else.

Comment: @Kilarn123 the domain is ok and it's running , when I remove "android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" , it installs but it returns  the "Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted" error , I'm really confused

Comment: Well you can try `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` directly in your manifest as @Piyush suggested, it should accept http trafic. the two ways work on my projects so there is no reason it wouldn't work in one of yours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize AndroidManifest.xml